# product search not working properly in solr 8.11 with SAPCommerceCloud 2205.7

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrj, solrcloud, solrclient

I am using solr 8.11 with hybris 2205.7 and sapmachine jdk 17

product search not working when searching with complete product code.

Ex: If my product code is 12345
I am getting results when searching with 123
but Not  getting result  when searching with 12345

During debugging I found below in case of complete code search(12345)

QueryResponse queryResponse = solrClient.query(index.getName(), solrQuery, method);

after execution of this "queryResponse._expandedResults" is 0

but when searching with 123 value of "_expandedResults" is greater than 0

This is making the difference...

Expecting to get the product:12345 when searching with the '12345'

Comment: Did you check the solr side? Maybe you are indexing just part of product code.

Comment: log solr query and analyse it , just add solrQueryDebuggingListener in your index-type to print logs in console.